# Strings broken with special character at Login ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, ionic-framework

I'm working with a Login problem in my app. I have an oauth login implemented between my server and my app, login works right, but if I use a password generated by some online services or app dedicated, for example, **`/#+6-[[?!nWYvfL)2Z7`** the url that I need to build to make a call to the server, fails.

This is the call that my app generate:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(521)] "http://localhost/oauth/v2/token?client_id=18_5cf03buhhp8gafadfg088w440ogsgd08ooggso80wg000k0gccw08&client_secret=4ajo9kcdqbqagddagdfdfswwcoo0c4gk48g4okw4kck0k0&grant_type=password&username=testing&password=/#+6-[[?!nWYvfL)2Z7", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/factoryutils.js (521)
```

It's seems to break after the dash. How I can solve this issue??

Thank you.

EDIT:

After insert ' ', it's still fails. The logcat of Android Studio show me the URL like an hyperlink, but until the password, like the next:

[http://localhost/oauth/v2/token?client_id=18_5cf03buhhp8gafadfg088w440ogsgd08ooggso80wg000k0gccw08&client_secret=4ajo9kcdqbqagddagdfdfswwcoo0c4gk48g4okw4kck0k0&grant_type=password&username=testing&password=](http://No,%20I'm%20just%20see%20that%20it%20continues%20failing.%20The%20logcat%20of%20Android%20Studio%20show%20me%20the%20URL%20like%20an%20hyperlink,%20but%20until%20the%20password,%20like%20the%20next:%20%20http://localhost/oauth/v2/token?client_id=18_5cf03buhhp8gafadfg088w440ogsgd08ooggso80wg000k0gccw08&client_secret=4ajo9kcdqbqagddagdfdfswwcoo0c4gk48g4okw4kck0k0&grant_type=password&username=testing&password=)'/#+6-[[?!nWYvfL)2Z7'

Comment: Try sending `'/#+6-[[?!nWYvfL)2Z7'` istead of `/#+6-[[?!nWYvfL)2Z7`, it seems like a special character is causing trouble that can be prevented like so.

Comment: The password is retrieved by $scope.user.password, how can I put it, like that? "... ' " + $scope.user.password + " ' ..."

Comment: `var password = "'"+$scope.user.password+"'";` will wrap your password in `'`'s.

Comment: Ok, thank you, and sorry for the last noob question. :)

Comment: I suppose it worked? If so, let me change my comment to an answer for proper question closure. And no problem, a question is a question, and it was asked well too ;)

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, i think i misassumed what can define a string in a URL, try `\"` instead, it will be unescaped when you call the URL and be a simple `"`.

Comment: ...+ "\"" + pass + "\""; like that?

Comment: Exactly! Just like before but with `\"`.

Comment: Same result, but with ". Sorry

Comment: Answer should solve it this time, `/` cannot be placed in POST data of a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Send `"%2F#+6-[[?!nWYvfL)2Z7"` instead of `/#+6-[[?!nWYvfL)2Z7`, this should solve your problem.

It is achieved like this:

```
var unEscapedPassword = "\""+$scope.user.password+"\"";
var escapedPassword = unEscapedPassword .replace("/", "%2F");
```

Answer (score 0):

With the next code I can get url with the password formatted.

```
function encodeRFC5987ValueChars (str) {
                return encodeURIComponent(str).
                    // Note that although RFC3986 reserves "!", RFC5987 does not,
                    // so we do not need to escape it
                    replace(/['()]/g, escape). // i.e., %27 %28 %29
                    replace(/\*/g, '%2A').
                        // The following are not required for percent-encoding per RFC5987, 
                        // so we can allow for a little better readability over the wire: |`^
                        replace(/%(?:7C|60|5E)/g, unescape);
            }
```

Thank you for your help Tarekis

Comment: Okay, you got a whole encoding function that's working i see, which would fit everything. Just fiddled [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/23b1xmm2/) before you got it yourself. :)